# DirectoryAPI Users groups taking 3-4 days to update

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I have webhooks/push-notifications (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/push) set up to send directory events to an endpoint. We have noticed that certain events such as a user being added to a group, or a new group being created can take days to arrive. However, We refresh the notification channels every five hours.

A few questions:

Has there been any kind of delay with these notifications?

Is there any kind of logs within the Google Admin settings that show the updates being
sent?

Is there any kind of troubleshooting we can receive to speed up the events?

Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: So it's not `groups taking 3-4 days to update`, but notifications for it taking 3-4 days to arrive, right? There should not be this kind of delay, it's suggest reporting this in Issue Tracker if you have a way to reliably reproduce this.

Comment: Yes that's correct - notifications taking 3-4 days to arrive! I have a test environment up and running and will log the behavior for reproducing - thanks for the pointer about issue tracker

Comment: Do you see that for all events in the API? Or just for users being added to groups?

Comment: Only for users being added/dropped from groups - I Was able to validate the events with solid timestamps in the Google Admin UI but still cannot see group add/drop events coming through that were configured 5+ days ago. Would it be possible to reach out via e-mail with a specific example for you to look into?